# dbt Snapshot using Variable as source & DAG lineage

Tags: jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I've got 3 main questions;

I've created a Snapshot, but instead of referencing a Source using the Source() function I have used variables that can be passed from the command line.
(My plan is to get Azure Data Factory to run a dbt Snapshot on the end of importing a source).

At the moment I'm testing in Visual Studio Code running from Powershell using the command

```
dbt run --vars '{"SourceSch": "SourceExampleSchema", "SourceTble": "SrcTbl"}'
```

In the snapshot I've got the following;

```
{% snapshot SrcTbl %}
```

At the moment I can't get "SrcTbl" to populate from the variable so I've had to hard code it.
I've tried the following results in an object called "var".

```
{% snapshot var("SourceTble") %}
```

1. Can anyone tell me how to reference the variable in the snapshot name?
2. When the docs are served only the snapshot table is a node, the source isn't listed.
   Is this the default behaviour or is it because I'm not calling the Source() function?
   How would I get the DAG to pick up the source going into the Snapshot?

Then I'm looking to expand this through Jinja so that it creates a snapshot for each "SourceTble".
3. How would I expand it if I had the following structure;

```
Database
    -> Schema 1
        -> Table 1
    -> Schema 2
        -> Table 2
        -> Table 3
```

I think it would be something like;

```
dbt run --vars '{"SourceSch": ["Schema1", "SourceTble": "Table1", "Schema2", "SourceTble": ["Table2", "Table3"]]}'
```

But I'm confused on how to use Jinja to create a .sql file for each table using the one as a base.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Why isnt hard-coding a snapshot for a specific table no solution for you? I would stay away from coupling the snapshot name to some variable. At some point you change the factory and the underlying snapshot is no longer working.

There are certainly cases where this is useful. But sounds like premature optimization right now for just a couple of sources and the coupling is a real issue (from own experience)

Comment: I'd be keen to hear more about your experience?
I'm not looking at a few Databases / Schemas / Tables.
(That's why I'm trying to go this route).